# svn rename package name and project name: one or two transaction?

Tags: svn, transactions, rename

for a project with 1000+ source files, rename both project name and package name, should I do it in one transaction or two transactions? For example,

```
project name: foo  --->  bar
root package name: com.mycompany.foo ---> com.mycompany.bar
```

Under each project:

```
foo/trunk
foo/branches
foo/tags
```

Answer (score 0):

That's up to you. You can make two commits or one commit. Checkout a working copy with your project, make your modifications and commit them as a single atomic commit.